# Android: Listview nullpointer exception without cause

Tags: android, listview, scroll, nullpointerexception

I am trying to display a ListView from an ArrayList defined in the Application class. However, I end up with a NullPointerException whenever I scroll with no cause given the in the Logcat.

**LogCat output:**

```
05-17 11:05:35.365: W/System.err(2173): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 11:05:35.375: W/System.err(2173):     at in.net.maloo.HomeScreenListView$myAdapter.getView(HomeScreenListView.java:66)
05-17 11:05:35.385: W/System.err(2173):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
05-17 11:05:35.385: W/System.err(2173):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
05-17 11:05:35.395: W/System.err(2173):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
05-17 11:05:35.395: W/System.err(2173):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:623)
05-17 11:05:35.395: W/System.err(2173):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:2944)
05-17 11:05:35.405: W/System.err(2173):     at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:2485)
05-17 11:05:35.405: W/System.err(2173):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-17 11:05:35.405: W/System.err(2173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-17 11:05:35.415: W/System.err(2173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-17 11:05:35.415: W/System.err(2173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-17 11:05:35.415: W/System.err(2173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 11:05:35.425: W/System.err(2173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-17 11:05:35.425: W/System.err(2173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-17 11:05:35.425: W/System.err(2173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-17 11:05:35.425: W/System.err(2173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Code:**

```
package in.net.maloo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeScreenListView extends ListActivity {

    private static class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public myAdapter(Context context){
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return myApp.feedLength(0);
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View conertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (conertView == null) {
                conertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_homescreen, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.text1 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_symbol);
                holder.text2 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_price);
                holder.text3 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_unit);
                holder.text4 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_change);
                holder.text5 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_pcp);
            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) conertView.getTag();
            }

            String com, ltp, volume, ltq, pcp;
            com = myApp.getFuturesData(position, "Commodity", 0) + " - " + myApp.getFuturesData(position, "Expiry", 0);
            ltp = myApp.getFuturesData(position, "LTP") + "";
            ltq = "LTQ: " + myApp.getFuturesData(position, "LTQ");
            volume = "Volume: " + myApp.getFuturesData(position, "Volume");
            pcp = "PCP: " + myApp.getFuturesData(position, "PCP");

            try {

            holder.text1.setText(com);
            Log.e("Position", com);
            holder.text2.setText(ltp);
            holder.text3.setText(volume);
            holder.text4.setText(ltq);
            holder.text5.setText(pcp);
            return conertView;
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                return conertView;
            }
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView text1;
            TextView text2;
            TextView text3;
            TextView text4;
            TextView text5;
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new myAdapter(this));        

}
}
```

**listview_homescreen layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hs_listview_symbol"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/hs_listview_change"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
            android:textSize="17dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hs_listview_price"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="28,788"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hs_listview_unit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Vol"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hs_listview_pcp"
            android:layout_width="75dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="PCP"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hs_listview_change"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Apparently, convertView.getTag() method is returning null for some reason, and hence all the problem. The same code was working fine when I was earlier using direct reference to an Array defined in myApp but then I switched to using ArrayList of a custom class holding different data types.

If it matters, the ListView activity is contained inside a Tabhost containing 3 tabs.

Any help with this will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  If you thought something was really helpful you could also upvote it (click the up arrow next to the answer).  Good luck!

Comment: This is a 6 year old question. If you are down voting my posts from medieval age, at the very least please post a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (conertView == null) {
   conertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_homescreen, null);
   holder = new ViewHolder();

   holder.text1 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_symbol);
   holder.text2 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_price);
   holder.text3 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_unit);
   holder.text4 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_change);
   holder.text5 = (TextView) conertView.findViewById(R.id.hs_listview_pcp);
   **conertView.setTag(holder);**
} else {
  holder = (ViewHolder) conertView.getTag();
}
```

you were missing **conertView.setTag(holder);**

Comment: Completely wrong... convertView.setTag(holder) when you are creating a new view (when convertView = null)

Comment: sorry my mistake instead of set i wrote get

Comment: Thought that might be it, which is why I didn't immediately downvote it.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was doing something stupid because all my other lists were working except this one, and I don't know how I missed the settag up there. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing `convertView.setTag(yourtag);`, so of course `getTag()` is returning null.

Just add the at the end of your `if (conertView == null)` before the `else`.